# Force Angular flex-layout check the layout size

Tags: angular, angular-flex-layout

I am using flex-layout with Angular8 and using [golden-layout](https://golden-layout.com/) to arrange my components in dockable windows, my problem is the layout in my components is changed according to the flex-layout only when I resize the browser window, and when I resize the component window nothing changed, something like the flex-layout is not notified about the resize as I think.

```
<div fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayout.xs="column">
  <label fxFlex="50">Name: </label>
  <mat-form-field fxFlex="50">
    <input matInput [ngModel]="_name" placeholder="Feature name" name="tst">
  </mat-form-field>

  <label fxFlex="50">Description: </label>
  <mat-form-field fxFlex="50">
    <input matInput [ngModel]="_desc" placeholder="Feature Description" name="tstD">
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

My layout should change to `column` when the component's window width is below 599px, but this happens only when I resize the browser window.

Are my thoughts right? and if yes, how can I notify the flex-layout about the component's window size change?